# Doctrine doesn't fetch changed entities that aren't persisted yet

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

```
$objectRepository = $objectManager->getRepository(MyEntity::class);
$myEntity = $objectRepository->findOneBy(["name" => "AAA"]); // returns an object
$myEntity->changeName("BBB");
$myEntity = $objectRepository->findOneBy(["name" => "BBB"]); // doesn't return anything
```

I have some high level repository like UserRepository, ProductRepository, etc, with methods like ->add(User $user), or ->findByName($name), etc

And I use these Repositories across all my code to manipulate the entities, but since these entities are not persisted and flushed on EACH change, the Repositories cannot return changed entities because the doctrine's object repository cannot find the entities.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: D2 simply does not support this sort of functionality.  Don't know of any php libraries that do.

Comment: You forgot to persist an object after `$myEntity->changeName("BBB");`

Comment: Persist is not required, a flush is need for the code to work.  And of course flush is what the poster wants to avoid.